# How to add a search box with icon to the navbar in Bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using the new Twitter Bootstrap 3, and am trying to place a search box like this (below) **in the top navbar**:

[image: Navbar Search]

In Bootstrap 2, it could've ben done like this:

```
<form class="form-search" method="get" id="s" action="/">
    <div class="input-append">
        <input type="text" class="input-medium search-query" name="s" placeholder="Search" value="">
        <button type="submit" class="add-on"><i class="icon-search"></i></button>
    </div>
</form>
```

But I am not sure how to produce the same in Bootstrap 3 as so much has changed.

The default HTML for the navbar search box form in Bootstrap 3 is:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

How do I modify it to achieve what I need?

Comment: Useful bootstrap search box in navigation bar
http://www.designerslib.com/bootstrap-navbar-search-bar/

Comment: **Full-width** search input Bootstrap 4, [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39792188/171456)

Answer (score 216, accepted):

I'm running BS3 on a dev site and the following produces the effect/layout you're requesting.  Of course you'll need the glyphicons set up in BS3.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-static-top" role="navigation">

    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" rel="home" href="/" title="Aahan Krish's Blog - Homepage">ITSMEEE</a>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="/topic/notes/">/notes</a></li>
            <li><a href="/topic/dev/">/dev</a></li>
            <li><a href="/topic/good-reads/">/good-reads</a></li>
            <li><a href="/topic/art/">/art</a></li>
            <li><a href="/topic/bookmarks/">/bookmarks</a></li>
            <li><a href="/all-topics/">/all</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 pull-right">
        <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </form>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE: See [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/philnicholas/XfzFQ/)

Comment: This makes the search box look the way I want to, but breaks the navbar. I couldn't fix it without breaking the search box and vice-versa. :-/ Here's a screenshot: http://i.stack.imgur.com/vTfvX.png

Comment: @its_me:  I'm not sure why it breaks for you. I tested it *fully* on a live site before posting it. Perhaps it's where you were inserting it.  I'll update the answer with the full nav bar code I'm using. Personally I'd suggest right-aligning the search form, but it's up to you.

Comment: Phil, I haven't got a live site to test yet. So, I am testing it by replacing the example on the official bootstrap site, here: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar -- If you'd like to try, please do, or I'll check again when my site is up and let you know. Thanks for trying to help. +1

Comment: Okay, here's a confirmation that something is wrong with the code you provided. Code here: http://jsfiddle.net/36ykS/1/ - full page preview here: http://jsfiddle.net/36ykS/1/embedded/result/ -- maybe you are using some custom CSS to get it to work on your site?

Comment: I've forked your Fiddle and tweaked it: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/philnicholas/XfzFQ/) Based on the [BS3 docs for Button addons](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons) I think that's the best you're going to get. Note that I removed the non-visible field label, which returned the corner radius on the left side. I'll again update the answer code.

Comment: It still isn't working. Yes, when I looked the latest fiddle you provided, in Firefox, everything seems good. But in chrome, it's the same old story. It's broken like I showed here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/vTfvX.png

Comment: I don't give up that easy.  I've updated the Fiddle, and tested it IE10, Firefox, and Chrome.  The width of the text area varies a tad with window width, but I think it has the effect you're looking for.

Comment: Note to NOOBs ---> If  you down-vote something, at least take the time to comment about what was wrong with the solution that triggered the down-vote.

Comment: Just tried the jsfiddle in the answer and the hamburger is unresponsive on chrome.

Comment: Thanks @mickmackusa It seems JSFiddle's links to Bootstrap were no longer supported. So I've updated the fiddle to point directly to the Bootstrap CDN.  Its should be working now.

Answer (score 48):

This is the closest I could get without adding any custom CSS (this I'd already figured as of the time of asking the question; guess I've to stick with this):

[image: Navbar Search Box]

And the markup in use:

```
<form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
    </button>
</form>
```

**PS:** Of course, that can be fixed by adding a negative `margin-left` (-4px) on the button, and removing the `border-radius` on the sides `input` and `button` meet. But the whole point of this question is to get it to work without any custom CSS.

[image: Fixed Navbar Search box]

Answer (score 32):

You could use the segmented buttons example from Bootstrap 3:

```
<form action="" class="navbar-form navbar-right">
   <div class="input-group">
       <input type="Search" placeholder="Search..." class="form-control" />
       <div class="input-group-btn">
           <button class="btn btn-info">
           <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
           </button>
       </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

I tried @PhilNicholas 's code and got the same problem of @its_me said in the comments that search bar show up on the next line of navbar, and I found that `form` need to be added an attribute `width`.

```
<form role="search" style="width: 15em; margin: 0.3em 2em;">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Close, I found I needed to add a width to the input-group. `<div class="input-group" style="width:15em;">`

Answer (score 3):

This one I implemented for my website , If some one got more no's of menu item and longer search bar can use this

[image]

[image]

Here is the code

```
       <style>
        .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a {
            color: white !important;
        }

            .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
                text-decoration: underline;
            }

        .navbar-collapse ul li {
            padding-top: 0px;
            padding-bottom: 0px;
        }

            .navbar-collapse ul li a {
                padding-top: 0px;
                padding-bottom: 0px;
            }

        .navbar-brand img {
            width: 200px;
            height: 40px;
        }

        .navbar-inverse {
            background-color: #3A1B37;
        }
    </style>
   <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/200x40/3A1B37/ffffff/?text=Apllicatin"></a>
                <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8 col-xs-11 navbar-left">
                    <div class="navbar-form " role="search">
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name="srch-term" id="srch-term" style="max-width: 100%; width: 100%;">
                            <div class="input-group-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-default" style="background: rgb(72, 166, 72);" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="navbar-brand  visible-md visible-lg visible-sm" style="visibility: hidden;" runat="server">
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/200x40/3A1B37/ffffff/?text=Apllicatin" />
                    </li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Somthing</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Somthing</a></li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Register">Register</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Login">Log in</a></li>
                </ul> </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>3 Col Portfolio - Start Bootstrap Template</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>

<body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Start Bootstrap</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Services</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contact</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" name="keyword" placeholder="search..." class="form-control">
                        <span class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-default">Go</button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container -->
    </nav>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">

        <!-- Page Header -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <h1 class="page-header">Page Heading
                    <small>Secondary Text</small>
                </h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->

        <!-- Projects Row -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="">
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#">Project Name</a>
                </h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="">
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#">Project Name</a>
                </h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="">
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#">Project Name</a>
                </h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="">
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#">Project Name</a>
                </h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->

        <!-- Projects Row -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="">
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#">Project Name</a>
                </h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="">
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#">Project Name</a>
                </h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="">
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#">Project Name</a>
                </h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="">
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#">Project Name</a>
                </h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->

        <!-- Projects Row -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="">
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#">Project Name</a>
                </h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="">
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#">Project Name</a>
                </h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="">
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#">Project Name</a>
                </h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="">
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#">Project Name</a>
                </h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->

        <!-- Projects Row -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="">
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#">Project Name</a>
                </h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="">
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#">Project Name</a>
                </h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="">
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#">Project Name</a>
                </h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
                <a href="#">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://placehold.it/700x400" alt="">
                </a>
                <h3>
                    <a href="#">Project Name</a>
                </h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam viverra euismod odio, gravida pellentesque urna varius vitae.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->

        <hr>

        <!-- Pagination -->
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                <ul class="pagination">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">&laquo;</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="#">1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">2</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">3</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">4</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">5</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">&raquo;</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
    </div>
    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                    <h3>About</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> Your company address here
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></i> 0982.808.065
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></i> anhtuank7c@hotmail.com
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-flag"></i> <a href="#">Fan page</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></i> 08:00-18:00 Monday to Friday
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                    <h3>Support</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="link">Terms of Service</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="link">Privacy policy</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="link">Warranty commitment</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#" class="link">Site map</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                    <h3>Other</h3>
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
    </footer>

    <!-- /.container -->

    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```