# Bootstrap 3 Navigation Bar

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a Navigation bar using Bootstrap 3. Looks like there are a lot of changes in the new version and lot of classes are missing.

Previously i had something like the following and am trying to convert the same into the new version of Bootstrap.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse">
            <div class="navbar-inner">
                <div class="container">
                    <a href="" class="brand">Project Name</a>

                    <ul class="nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="">Link 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Link 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="">Link 3</a></li>
                        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                        <li><a href="">Link 4</a></li>
                        <li class="divider-vertical"></li>
                    </ul>

                    <form action="" class="navbar-search pull-right">
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="search-query" />
                    </form>     

                    <p class="navbar-text">This is a text.</p>  

                    <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">Show Content</a>

                    <div class="collapse nav-collapse">
                        <p class="navbar-text">This will be hidden.</p>
                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
```

I am sepecifically interested in the Search Form structure where i used to add the class `search-query` class to the input class.

Also do we still need to add the `navbar-inner` since the example in the official site doesnt use it.

Comment: It is not mentioned in the Migraton, but `.navbar-search` and `.search-query` were dropped as well...

Answer (score 4):

I'm directly using the navbar like this :

http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar is quite clear

- div is now nav
- you have to review also the structure inside remove maybe the container class
- you form action should be in form-group

> ```
> <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
>         <div class="navbar-header">
>             <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
>             <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
>             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
>             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
>             <span class="icon-bar"></span>
>           </button>
>           <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span> My Apps</a>
>         </div>
> ```

```
<!-- https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/10495 added 2px padding top to center icon -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse" style="padding-top: 2px;">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li><a href="Link_1.jsp">Link 1</a></li>
              <li><a href="Link_2.jsp">Link 2</a></li>
              <li><a href="Link_3.jsp">Link 3</a></li>
          </ul>

          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li>
                  <div class="navbar-form navbar-left">
                      <div class="form-group">
                          <input id="searchInput" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                      </div>
                      <button id="searchButton" class="btn btn-default"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span></button>
                  </div>
              </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 3):

Check this link for a nice overview of the required changes for migration.

http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#migration

The `navbar-inner` class for instance was dropped. This part of the new documentation should get you started: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar

For the `search-query` check this SO post: [How to add a search box with icon to the navbar in Bootstrap 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18619740/how-to-add-a-search-box-with-icon-to-the-navbar-in-bootstrap-3) (well it has all your answers in fact).