# Bootstrap search field with icon in navigation header not appearing correctly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm attempting to add a search box with a header to my Bootstrap 3 template. The template that I'm using was purchased from the Bootstrap themes page and is the [Light UI Dashboard](http://themes.getbootstrap.com/products/dashboard) theme.

I found this answer on Stack Overflow but it's not appearing correctly (it appears incorrectly in both Chrome and Edge).

[How to add a search box with icon to the navbar in Bootstrap 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18619740/how-to-add-a-search-box-with-icon-to-the-navbar-in-bootstrap-3)

I modified my code to include the search box in my header however the glyphicon doesn't display and the search box is out of alignment. Here is a screen shot.

[image]

My code is as follows:

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');
```

```html
<form runat="server">
  <!-- Fixed navbar -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Crown Ent.</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
          <li role="presentation" id="dashboard"><a href="./">Dashboard</a></li>
          <li role="presentation" id="workorders"><a href="workorders.aspx">Work Orders</a></li>
          <li role="presentation" id="invoices"><a href="invoices.aspx">Invoices</a></li>
          <li role="presentation" id="accounts"><a href="accounts.aspx">Accounts</a></li>
          <li role="presentation" id="people"><a href="people.aspx">People</a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a runat="server" href="~/admin">Settings</a></li>
          <li><a runat="server" href="~/admin">Help</a></li>
        </ul>

        <form class="navbar-form" style="padding-top:5px;">
          <div class="form-group" style="display:inline;margin-top:5px;">
            <div class="input-group" style="display:table;">
              <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></span>
              <input class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Search Here" id="crown-search" autocomplete="off" autofocus="autofocus" type="text">
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>

      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I can't see anything wrong with the code. Adjusting the CSS margin in an attempt to fix the positioning is also ineffective.

Comment: Did you correctly import the CSS and all of the glyph fonts?

Comment: @JackJamieson Yes, the CSS is imported correctly, as glyphicons appear elsewhere on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPD. I removed the first line `<form runat="server">` and used the code

```
  <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group">
```

instead of

```
  <form class="navbar-form" style="padding-top:5px;">
    <div class="form-group" style="display:inline;margin-top:5px;">
      <div class="input-group" style="display:table;">
```

And I've added some CSS to make the form wider. Please check the result.

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css');

#navbar .navbar-form {
  overflow: hidden;
}
#navbar .form-group,
#navbar .input-group {
  width: 100%;
}
#navbar .input-group-addon {
  width: 39px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Fixed navbar -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Crown Ent.</a>
    </div>
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
        <li role="presentation" id="dashboard"><a href="./">Dashboard</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" id="workorders"><a href="workorders.aspx">Work Orders</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" id="invoices"><a href="invoices.aspx">Invoices</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" id="accounts"><a href="accounts.aspx">Accounts</a></li>
        <li role="presentation" id="people"><a href="people.aspx">People</a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a runat="server" href="~/admin">Settings</a></li>
        <li><a runat="server" href="~/admin">Help</a></li>
      </ul>

      <form class="navbar-form" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></span>
            <input class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Search Here" id="crown-search" autocomplete="off" autofocus="autofocus" type="text">
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! The glyphicon appears and the search box is positioned correctly with one small caveat. The search box is at its default width. How do I get the search box to fill the length of the div element like in my original screenshot?

Comment: @Nse I've added some CSS to make the form wider. And I removed `navbar-righ` from `<form class="navbar-form" ....`. I've updated my answer. Please check new result.

Comment: @Nse Notice that the navbar has no space for the form when the screen width is between 768 and 991 pixels. You can add the `hidden-sm` class to your form.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is add the span that holds the search icon after the input field if you want it to be on the other side

So

```
<div class="input-group" style="display:table;">
     <input class="form-control" name="search" placeholder="Search Here" id="crown-search" autocomplete="off" autofocus="autofocus" type="text">
     <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></span>
</div>
```

Also just looks like you need to apply a margin-top value to the input-group class feel free to add another class called search or something to apply it too as well

This seems like a simple css fix

FYI the glyph icon appears in all 3 of my browsers (Chrome, FF, and IE)

Answer (score 0):

in order to fix out of alignment problem change this:

```
<div class="form-group" style="display:inline;margin-top:5px;">
```

to this:

```
<div style="margin-top:5px;">
```