# Bootstrap navbar with desired width and centralized

Tags: jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I am using Bootstrap 4 and would like to make the inline form in navbar to desired width when using on laptopn and extend to screen when using mobile devices.

How it appears in my mobile :
[image: Mobile View]

[image: Laptop View]

My HTML code is

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg fixed-top navbar-transparent " color-on-scroll="300" style="text-transform: capitalize;">
  <div class="d-flex flex-grow-1">
    <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">AutoGram</a>

    <form class="form-inline" action="/search">

      <div class="input-group mb-10 ">
        <input type="text" class="form-control from-control-sm"  id="q" name="q" placeholder="Enter Brand,Model,Variant for search" >
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <span class="input-group-text" style="color:whitesmoke; background-color: black;" id="SearchButton">Search</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
  <button class="navbar-toggler order-0" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar7">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
  <div class="navbar-collapse collapse flex-shrink-1 flex-grow-0 order-last" id="navbar7">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I would like to increase the width of the input box and position it centrally in laptop-view 
and in mobile-view , I would like the input group to extend till the toggle bar.

Comment: second image is on lap top screen right?

Comment: Yes, its from the laptop screen

Comment: and on a laptop you want the input to be in the center of the screen and on small devices to get full width?

Comment: Yes , full width along with logo and toggle bar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this CSS

```css
form {
  width: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  form {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

form div.input-group {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

It will increase the size of input on small screens to occupy all remaining space. And on the laptop I gave it `width: auto` but you can change this to anything you want.

Also, I gave input-group class `width: 100%` to match the size of `form`

Hope this helps. If it doesn't come back so we can work it out together :)

Comment: Yes , this helps. Mobile -View works as expected. Thank you. How do I make the form in the center of the page in laptop-view ? I tried adding a padding, but it reduces the length of the input.

Comment: Oh yeah.. sorry. Let me add that. Hold on

Comment: I updated the answer. I added margins to form. Check it out and tell me if it fits :)

Comment: Glad I could help :) 
Have fun

Answer (score 0):

You need to add CSS in MEDIA QUERY

```
 @media(max-width: 991px){
    .form-inline .input-group {
        width: 100%;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    form.form-inline {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Check here https://codepen.io/rvtech/pen/rNNEExJ

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify if you want it *horizontal* center, *vertical* center or both. Assuming you just want it horizontal center... Use the responsive flexbox utility classes (**no extra CSS or media queries are needed**)...

https://codeply.com/p/pQGzObPbLe

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-light fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-transparent justify-content-lg-center" color-on-scroll="300" style="text-transform: capitalize;">
    <div class="d-flex flex-grow-1 flex-lg-grow-0">
        <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">AutoGram</a>
        <form class="d-flex d-lg-inline flex-grow-1 flex-lg-grow-0" action="/search">
            <div class="input-group mb-10 ">
                <input type="text" class="form-control from-control-sm" id="q" name="q" placeholder="Enter Brand,Model,Variant for search">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <span class="input-group-text" style="color:whitesmoke; background-color: black;" id="SearchButton">Search</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <button class="navbar-toggler order-0" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar7">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse flex-shrink-1 flex-grow-0 order-last" id="navbar7">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think this could help you

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-SI27wrMjH3ZZ89r4o+fGIJtnzkAnFs3E4qz9DIYioCQ5l9Rd/7UAa8DHcaL8jkWt" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">AutoGram</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    
    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Enter Brand,Model,Variant for search" aria-label="Search">
      <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-3qaqj0lc6sV/qpzrc1N5DC6i1VRn/HyX4qdPaiEFbn54VjQBEU341pvjz7Dv3n6P" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: No, it doesn't work. It makes the button go to next row in mobile-view. Additionally, it does not increase the width in laptop-view

Comment: That is how bootstrap hides the search bar(form) . Otherwise it will not be responsive.please refer https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Comment: please don't give negative try to understand or let me know if you need any help