# how to make my logo, search bar and icon in a single row using bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, html, css

It is getting like this image.I want these three divs in one row. how can i get when it is done in bootstrap?

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2"> 

<div class="row" >   

<div class="wrap-content-header">
   <div class="wrap-logo">
                    <a href="#"> <img src="images/logo.jpg"></a>
                </div> </div>

      <div class='search-box'>
        <form class='search-form'>
          <input class='form-control'  type='text'>
          <button class='btn btn-link search-btn'>
            <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'> Search</i>
          </button>
        </form>

`enter code here`      </div>

 <span class="glyphicon-stack">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle glyphicon-stack-2x"></i>
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user glyphicon-stack glyphicon-stack-1x"></i>
</span>

</div>
</div>
</div>
```

[image]
It is looking like this now.
I want to make it as like this image

[[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMw1v.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0ATg.jpg)

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18619740/how-to-add-a-search-box-with-icon-to-the-navbar-in-bootstrap-3

Comment: sorry, it couldn't make the three divs in one row

Comment: what css have you tried? Using display: inline-block should result in it working - place all 3 divs in a parent container div and on the 3 divs add display: inline-block (as a class rule)

Comment: three divs in single row.. is it wrong to use..? output matters.. :)

Comment: @ZaheerAttar no it doesn't :) you can have a container div so they span the full width and then you can use display inline on the child divs (and set width to whatver) and they'll be inline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Please verify with the screenshot above.

Made some corrections in the div's structuring, let me know if it works for you.
You are using the grid layout of bootstrap.

First we create a row and then we can divide it into a space of 12 columns. 
So the total of all the columns in a row should not exceed 12 in total(including the offset if used)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">   
        <div class="col-xs-2 wrap-content-header col-xs-offset-1">
            <div class="wrap-logo">
                <a href="#"> <img src="images/logo.jpg"></a>
            </div> 
        </div>
        <div class='col-xs-6 search-box'>
            <form class='search-form'>
                <input class='form-control' type='text'>
                <button class='btn btn-link search-btn'>
                <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'> Search</i>
                </button>
            </form>
            `enter code here`      
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-2 col-xs-offset-1">
            <span class="glyphicon-stack">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle glyphicon-stack-2x"></i>
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user glyphicon-stack glyphicon-stack-1x"></i>
            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Working JS Fiddle Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/humotrj0/418/)

Comment: I just added the link to a working JS fiddle, please check it is working.

Comment: @Liza: If it worked for you, then in that case you can mark my answer as useful for the future refrences.

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap makes use of a 12-columns lay-out this means that on a single row you're able to put 12 columns max. Since you want 3 columns on one row try the following.

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2 wrap-content-header"> 
   <div class="col-xs-4 wrap-logo">
                    <a href="#"> <img src="images/logo.jpg"></a>
                </div>
      <div class='col-xs-4 search-box'>
        <form class='search-form'>
          <input class='form-control'  type='text'>
          <button class='btn btn-link search-btn'>
            <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-search'> Search</i>
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
 <span class="glyphicon-stack">
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle glyphicon-stack-2x"></i>
<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user glyphicon-stack glyphicon-stack-1x"></i>
</span>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Bootstrap consists of `Containers`, `rows` of each 12 columns max and `col` for the columns indication.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Are you using any extra `CSS` ?